# PyQt4 and 64-bit python

Tags: python, dll, 64-bit, pyqt

I am trying to get the 64-bit version of python up and running with a program I wrote. That program uses a gui I wrote in PyQt4. I cannot find a 64-bit version of PyQt4 and I get the following error when attempting to use the 32-bit of PyQt4 with the 64-bit version of python:

```
S:\src>SimLauncher.py
Forcing DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "SimLauncher.py", line 42, in <module>
   from SwSim import SwSim
 File "SwSim.py", line 13, in <module>
   from PyQt4 import QtSql,QtGui
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Clearly there is an incompatibly. I tried this fix, but I got the same error:

http://code.google.com/p/pyqt4-win64-binaries/downloads/list

Lemme know if you know how to solve this!

Comment: Have you looked at PySide? It has a better license than PyQt and is a Nokia project. http://www.pyside.org/

Comment: I've already developed a 1000 line gui in PyQt4 :/

Comment: PySide is very compatible with PyQt - you would probably only need to change the imports to `from PySide import ...` rather than `from PyQt import ...`

Comment: @sje397: no x86-64 Win32 binaries for PySide yet.  @tylerthemiler: PySide is largely API-compatible with PyQt4 - normally you'll be able to just change imports from PyQt4 to PySide and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, only problem is that I don't see a 64-bit version of PySide...so I'd have the same problem I think...

Comment: 64 bit version is available now: http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

64 bit PyQt binaries for Windows are available at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt

Update: 64 bit PyQt4 binaries for Windows, including the MySQL extension, are now officially available from Riverbank at http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download

Comment: The dlls are named weird, QtCore4.dll instead of QtCore.dll...and its throwing weird errors. When I try from PyQt4 import QtCore:

Comment: QtCore4.dll is the same 'weird' name the official PyQt4 distribution is using. Your previous 32 bit PyQt4 installation in the 64 bit Python site-packages folder is probably interfering with the 64 bit PyQt4 files. Try clean up your previous PyQt4 installation and make sure the 64 bit DLLs are found in the Windows DLL search path before the 32 bit ones.

Comment: The binary works, except it has two copies of the dlls, if you delete the dlls in the main folder and leave the ones in bin, they work.

Only problem is this installation did not have the optional pyqt sql stuff I also needed, so it didn't really solve the problem for me, but for anyone who doesn't need the extra qt sql package, this works great for win7 64bit intel!

Answer (score 1):

You can install PyQt4 using 64bit architecture, try looking here http://eoyilmaz.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-compile-pyqt4-for-windows-x64.html

Haven't tried it but I did something similar on OSX

Comment: Yeah, I saw that link...I was looking for something that didn't involve so much compiling and such as I'm inexperienced with that. I guess there is no binary anywhere??

Comment: There's a binary on this page: http://www.ozgurfx.com/downloads/PyQt-Py2.6-gpl-4.5.4-1_amd64.exe

(source from: http://eoyilmaz.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-compile-pyqt4-for-windows-x64.html)

The only thing is that you might want another/more recent version of PyQt ...

Comment: Does it matter that its for AMD?? I tried the binary at the bottom of the page on this answer, but it did't work, but it was for Python 2.5, whereas I'm using 2.6. So I don't know if the problem is AMD (I'm using Intel) or Python version.

Comment: No it doesn't matter ... just make sure it fits the Python version (2.6 in your case)