# ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore

Tags: python

I've reïnstalled my ssh server, so I also need to reïnstall my Python packages.

I did that, but I still get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore
```

I've already successfully installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```

But still it don't work, so I tried the installation [instruction of PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download)

So I've tried to install SIP first, but when I run "make" [(see end of this page, *"Building"*)](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/sip4/installation.html)

But I get this error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/francis/Downloads/sip-4.12.4/sipgen'
g++  -o sip main.o transform.o gencode.o extracts.o export.o heap.o parser.o lexer.o 
make[1]: g++: Command not found
make[1]: *** [sip] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/francis/Downloads/sip-4.12.4/sipgen'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What do I have to do? Or is there an other way to install PyQt4?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `apt-get install python-qt4`.

Comment: https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to install the `python-qt4` package - no need to recompile it yourself.

`sudo apt-get install python-qt4`

Comment: FWIW, I had a similar problem with a windows box.  The script runs fie on my Linux machine, with the same python version. You can download the correct binary (get the one that matches your python installation) from:
http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same error - `ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtGui`. Instead of running your python file (which uses PyQt) on the terminal as -

```
python file_name.py
```

Run it with sudo privileges -

```
sudo python file_name.py
```

This worked for me!

Comment: This is generally a bad idea.  Firstly, if you are running python in a virtualenv (which you should), then sudo will make the process step out of that.  It's also not portable, it can be unsafe... Better to figure out how to install in your environment correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when uninstalled my Python27 and re-installed it.

I downloaded the sip-4.15.5 and PyQt-win-gpl-4.10.4 and installed/configured both of them. it still gives 'ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore'. I tried to move the files/folders in Lib to make it looked 'have' but not working.

in fact, jut download the **Windows 64 bit installer** for a suitable Python version (my case) from http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download and installed it, will do the job.

*** March 2017 update ***

The given link says, Binary installers for Windows are no longer provided.

See cgohlke's answer at, [PyQt4 and 64-bit python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381936/pyqt4-and-64-bit-python).

1. Download the .whl file at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4.
2. Use pip to install the downloaded .whl file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the "No module named PyQt4.QtCore" error and installing the python-qt4 package fixed it only partially: I could run

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL
```

from a python interpreter but only without activating my virtualenv.

The only solution I've found till now to use a virtualenv is to copy the PyQt4 folder and the sip.so file into my virtualenv as explained here:
[Is it possible to add PyQt4/PySide packages on a Virtualenv sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961997/is-it-possible-to-add-pyqt4-pyside-packages-on-a-virtualenv-sandbox)

Comment: Thanks .. but where i can find the sip.so file?

Comment: @Kukku sorry, but I have no idea. My answer is 5 years old, I don't even remember what is sip.so.

Comment: I found the solution, it is there in the site packages folder itself.. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

You don't have g++ installed, simple way to have all the needed build tools is to install the package build-essential:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

, or just the g++ package:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, when I was trying to import matplotlib.pyplot

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
...
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore
```

But in my case the problem was due to a missing linux library **libGL.so.1**

OS : Cent OS 64 bit

Python version : 3.5.2

```
$> locate libGL.so.1
```

If this command returns a value, your problem could be different, so please ignore my answer. If it does not return any value and your environment is same as mine, below steps would fix your problem.

```
$> yum install mesa-libGL.x86_64
```

This installs the necessary OpenGL libraries for 64 bit Cent OS.

```
$> locate libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1
```

Now go back to iPython and try to import

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This time it imported successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to solve your problem.

```
sudo apt install build-essential python3-dev libqt4-dev
```

This works for me in python3.