# pyqt4.core Import error: no module named Core

Tags: python, apt-get

Just learning Python here and I can't seem to get my python program to work from line 2 :

```
from PyQt4.Core import *
```

I get the following error:

> ImportError: no module named Core

From what I can see, usually the programmer is just missing part of python-qt4
I have tried installing (or re-installing as the case may be) the following packages using `apt-get`, but surprisingly to no avail:

```
python-qt4 pyqt-tools pyside-tools libqt4-dev build-essential python-sip
```

I also tried using the interactive shell to do:

```
PyQt4.Core import SIGNAL
```

Where I get the same message

`apt-get` shows that I have the latest version of everything. I recently did an `apt-get update` and an `apt-get upgrade`, after installing the above packages then tried `apt-get install`(each) again. The update had all packages show most recent version is installed.

Still I get the same error message :(

Comment: Take a look here at this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119844/importerror-no-module-named-pyqt4-qtcore).

Comment: It's `QtCore`, not `Core`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it :)