# PyQt Python GUI to Windows application

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I created a Python GUI using pyqt4 and after converting it into an exe and running it I am get the following error:

```
**import error: DLL load failed %1 is not a valid win32 application** .
```

I tried pyinstaller, cx_freeze and even py2exe but got the same error. From the errors I understood that it's not importing **PyQt4.QtGui** and **PyQt4.QtCore** so i changed the of importing but got the same error and all Pyqt4, python 2.7 **win x64 version** so please help me out.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with missing Python imports. You've probably installed a 32-bit version of Qt, which can't be used with 64-bit Python.

Comment: Both are 64bit versions but still I got the error

Comment: Did you find out what the issue was? If not, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381936/pyqt4-and-64-bit-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah i got the solution , initially i was trying to create win application in linux using wine with python and qt4 as 64bit but when i tried the same thing in windows os using pyinstaller it created an exe file....(i still dont known the reason why)